# how to access the url outside the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a web frontend and web api app and both has docker support and here is the docker compose file for it.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
webfrontend:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webfrontend
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: WebFrontEnd/Dockerfile

mywebapi:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mywebapi
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: MyWebAPI/Dockerfile
```

Since both application shares same network, so internally DNS resolves and I am able to access web api from frontend app like below,

```
 using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            // Call *mywebapi*, and display its response in the page
            var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
            request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://mywebapi/WeatherForecast");
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            
        }
```

Here the web api url `http://mywebapi/WeatherForecast` ONLY accessible to the frontend app within code (internally) but when I am trying to browse this url over browser or postman, it's failing.

- What is the reason for it ? (browser or postman not in container network?)
- how we can access it outside the container? Do I need to use IP and port or DNS can also I can use?
- can I access same `http://mywebapi/WeatherForecast` outside?

Comment: try running with `--net=host` or using `EXPOSE <port number>`

Comment: add port mapping in docker-compose file to map port from host machine to port inside container. and once port mapping is done, access service from `localhost:<port>` from your host machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the reason for it ? (browser or postman not in container network?)

Yes, DNS resolution is done only for internal network so `mywebapi` is undefined outside the network defined by docker-compose.

> how we can access it outside the container? Do I need to use IP and port or DNS can also I can use?

You have to map ports of your host machine with ports which your containers expose (ports on which app is listening). There is a section in docker-compose like

```
  ...
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"    # maps 8000 port of host to 8000 port inside container
  ...
  ...
```

once port mapping is done you can `use http://localhost:<port>/` to access the service from outside docker network

> can I access same http://mywebapi/WeatherForecast outside?

No, and yes, you can define a mapping to resolve `mywebapi` to `localhost` in `/etc/hosts` file (for *NIX env. only)

Comment: Thanks @oli. Could you please give more info/article on .... etc/hosts file (for *NIX env. only)?

Comment: I can give you a brief intro here in comments. In early days of internet`/etc/hosts` file was used for resolution to find addresses for hostname (before DNS) so even if you see it today it contains a line `127.0.0.1     localhost` which defines that `localhost` is mapped to your loopback address `127.0.0.1` and in a similar way you can add a new line `127.0.0.1     mywebapi.com` to use `mywebapi.com` as hostname instead of localhost.

Comment: Thanks @oli. appreciate!